# Starting nginx and server at system restart

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, nginx, startup

I have two batch files which will start my nginx and node server ( using node forever) separately.

I want these scripts to restart every time the whole system restarts.
Now my server is a windows VM(windows server 2016) which has multiple users.

I tried [this](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000322.htm) but it creates a startup folder under my user, so I am guessing it will restart each time my user logs in and moreover my user folder will be deprecated.

I DO NOT want to start the scripts each time a user logs in.

Only when the system/VM restarts. How can I ensure that this happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the shortcut in Windows startup.  Take a look at this [link](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-Nginx-as-a-service-in-Windows).

Comment: The answer specifies that nginx will start running omce the user logs in.
I want it to run on every restart and for all users.

Comment: To start the service for all users, add nginx as Windows service, with nssm. http://oss-world.blogspot.com/2015/10/install-nginx-as-windows-service-using.html?m=1

Comment: ok done with windows scheduler.
Can you tell me how can I check if tasks are running under forever just as the script in the link checked for nginx?

Comment: It is recommended that you create a healthcheck in the nodeJS application to see if the server is running. https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-healthcheck